# EF Core: conditional query inside Include method

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to do a conditional query inside a *Include* method.

My entity classes look like this:

```cs
class Organization
{
    public ICollection<User> Users {get;set;}
}

class User
{
    public string Type {get; set;}
}
```

I want to find users inside a organization with certain Type, my current solution looks like this:

```cs
var organization = db.Organizations.Include(o => o.Users).FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == "1234");
string type = "TypeA" // if type is empty or null, then we don't need the Where statement.
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
{
    return organization.Users.Where(u => u.Type == "TypeA").ToList();
}
else
{
    return organization.Users.ToList();
}
```

But this method must first query all users inside the organization, and then do the filtering, which causes extra cost.

Is there any way to do *if ... then ...* inside the `Include(o => o.Users)` method? Or is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try flipping the LINQ query to:

```cs
db.Users.Where(u => u.OrganizationId == "1234" && u.Type == "TypeA").ToList();
```

Assuming you have a fairly standard EF model with an `OrganizationId` foreign key in your `User` entity class.

This will result in a single SQL query to the `User` table

Comment: Is this slower than finding organization first and then filtering the organization's users? Since my Organization table is pretty small (like 10 entries), and the User table can be pretty large.

Comment: @Nowayout I would suggest actually profiling the SQL queries generated before making a conclusion which is faster/slower. My best guess is my version is actually going to be faster because your code could translate to an `INNER JOIN` across two tables while mine is a `SELECT` on one single table. But this is all just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the answer, what you can use is:

```
var query = db.Users.Where(u => u.OrganizationId == organizationId);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
    query = query.Where(u => u.Type == type);
var users = query.ToList();
return users;
```

As for would this be slower? No, in the case where you have a "type" to search for this will be faster since the query will only fetch the users of that type specific to the organization ID. In your original case you are fetching all users for the organization into memory including all columns from the Organization, then filtering out the specific type if applicable when all we want are the users.

So if Organization has 10 columns and user has 10 columns and the organization has 10 users, your original query will return 10 rows of 20 columns to construct the organization and all users. (`AsSplitQuery` would reduce this to 1 row of 10 columns for the Organization and 10 rows of 10 columns for the users) These results would be returned from the DB whether you specify a Type or not.

In the above example, no data from the Organization is needed or returned, so if no Type filter is specified it would just return 10 rows of 10 columns for the users. If a Type filter is provided to return just 2 Users, then 2 rows would be returned. Less data coming back means faster queries, less work & memory to populate/track entities.